# Set incomparables globally in R

Tags: r

For some reason `match()` treats `NaN`'s as comparables by default:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,NaN,4,5)
> match(x,x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

which I can override when using `match()` directly:

```
> match(x,x,incomparables=NaN)
[1]  1  2  3 NA  5  6
```

but not necessarily when calling a function that uses `match()` internally:

```
> ecdf(x)(x)
[1] 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.8 1.0
```

Obviously there are workarounds for any given scenario, but the bigger problem is that this behavior causes difficult to discover bugs.  Hence, it would be preferable to set incomparables to include `NaN`'s globally in my [`.Rprofile` or `.Rprofile.site`](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html).  Is there a way to do so?

For reference, I'm using R version 3.2.2